# How would i be able to sort the category that i filtered with MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

> How would i be able to sort the category that i filtered with MYSQL?
>   For example i would like to get the cheapest hat.What would i have to do?

```
 if(isset($_GET['category'])){
        $category = $_GET['category'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE category='$category'";}else{
        $sql = "SELECT id,title,image FROM store";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['category'],$_GET['value'])){
        $currentPage = $_GET['category'];
        $value = $_GET['value'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE category='$category'ORDER BY $value";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['value'])) {
        if($_GET['value'] == 'price') {
            // query to get all by price 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY price";  
        }  
        elseif($_GET['value'] == 'title') {  
            // query to get all by title
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY title";  
        } elseif($_GET['value']== 'date') {  
            // query to get all by date added
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY date_added";  
        }
```

`

```html
<div id="filters">
  <a href="stores.php">All</a> 
        <a href="stores.php?category=t-shirt">T-Shirt</a>
        <a href="stores.php?category=mug">Mug</a>
        <a href="stores.php?category=hat">Hat</a>
 </div>
 <label for="sort">Sort By</label>
 <select name="sort">
 <option value="price">Price: Low to High</option>
 <option value="title">Title: A-Z</option>
 <option value="date">Newest</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

/*****
To my eyes I do not see how you can get what you want by using your given HTML. So what I've done is placing category and sort as form inputs. In this way we can easily manipulate with category and sort.

The form method here is GET. POST would have meant if(isset($_POST)).

Hope this helps.
******/
// Define category
if(isset($_GET['category'])){

$category = $_GET['category'];

}

// Define order of result
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){

$sort = $_GET['sort'];

}

// When the form is submitted
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Select based on category input and order result based on sort input
$sql = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY $sort";

}

<forrm action="store.php" method="GET">

<label for="category">Category</label>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="t-shirt">T-Shirt</option>
        <option value="mug">Mug</option>
        <option value="hat">Hat</option>
    </select>

```
<label for="sort">Sort By</label>
<select name="sort">
<option value="price">Price: Low to High</option>
<option value="title">Title: A-Z</option>
<option value="date">Newest</option>
</select>
```

<input type='submit' name='submit' />

</form>

Comment: no i would like to make a conditional statement where i could filter and sort it at the same time for example  SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY price WHERE category=$category with my conditional statement i can only sort all the items. i can't filter and sort it at the same time.